# Making RichTextBox for Touch

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `RichTextBox` in a `SurfaceWindow`. I need the RichTextBox because I'm required to make something like a sticky note (text and images as input), and `SurfaceTextBox` can't seem to put in images.

The problem is, the RichTextBox doesn't respond when I touch it on the screen. It only focuses when I click it with the mouse. I understand that this is because RichTextBox is not made for Surface.

Is there any other way I can achieve this (making the RichTextBox focusable through touch)?

Comment: Have you tried just setting focus on the text box?  This [Windows Touch Scratch pad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940546(v=vs.85).aspx) sample seems to have all the parts to be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I added a PreviewTouchDown event to the RichTextBox and set focus() to it and it works, didnt know why didn't I thought of that haha. The link you provided is for winforms.